# Can I set up AWS ELB to load balance requests to servers outside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, load-balancing

I have two custom hardware servers running a service for me, need to set up a load balancer. Till I can get my service provider to provide one for me, can I set up AWS ELB to load balance requests to my servers? Is there some other option? PS: Costs are an issue, so looking for cheaper alternatives

Comment: No you can't. You can only register EC2 instances as targets in a target group https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/target-group-register-targets.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks.
Would you also know reviews for any "load balancer as a service" provider? Or any other cloud service provider that I can use for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't :)